# How to write code results (that are within a void function) to a text file in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program that loads a "grades.txt" file that contains 20 numbers and calculates the standard deviation and outputs the results both on the screen as well as in a separate text file titled "results.txt"

The programs works great and outputs the results I am looking for. the only thing is, i cannot seem to figure out how to take the calculated results (i.e sum, mean, standard deviation) and output it into a text file.

The output text file i have in the code is successfully outputting the "results" message i am sending to it.

I just do not know how to take the results that are within the "void filereadernc(ifstream &file)" function and output in the text file of the "void filewriter(ofstream &file)" function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

// calling std name space
using namespace std;

void fileopenner(ifstream &file);
void filereader(ifstream &file);
void filecloser(ifstream &file);
void filereadernc(ifstream &file);
void filecreate(ofstream &file);
void filewriter(ofstream &file);
void filecloser(ofstream &file);

int main()
{
// declaration
ifstream ecet;
ofstream result;

// opening onc again
fileopenner(ecet);
filereadernc(ecet);
filecloser(ecet);
filecreate(result);
filewriter(result);
filecloser(result);

cout << endl;

return 0;
} // the end of the main function

void fileopenner(ifstream &file)
{
file.open("C:/Users/Desktop/grades.txt"); // file location on flash drive
}

void filereader(ifstream &file) // reading the values from the text file
{

int list[20];
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    file >> list[i];
}

void filereadernc(ifstream &file) // file reader
{
float sum = 0.0, mean = 0.0, standardDeviation = 0.0;

int list[100];
int j = 0;
file >> list[j];


while (!file.eof())
{
    j++;
    file >> list[j];
}
cout << "The input values: "; // display the values that were in the text file to the user

for (int i = 0; i <= j; i++)
    cout << list[i] << " ";

for (int i = 0; i <= j; i++) // calculate the sum and mean
{
    sum += list[i];
    mean = sum / 20;
}
for (int i = 0; i <= j; i++) // after finding the mean, we compute the standard deviation
    standardDeviation += pow(list[i] - mean, 2);

cout << endl;
cout << "The sum of all our values = " << sum; // display the mean of all the values in the text file
cout << endl;
cout << "The mean of all our values = " << mean; // display the mean of all the values in the text file
cout << endl;
cout << "The standard deviation = " << sqrt(standardDeviation / 20); // display the standard deviation
}

void filecloser(ifstream &file)
{
file.close();
}

void filecreate(ofstream &file)
{
file.open("C:/Users/Desktop/results.txt");
}

void filewriter(ofstream &file)
{

file << "results";

}

void filecloser(ofstream &file)
{
file.close();
}
```

Comment: This code looks way overcomplicated. `ofstream::open` and `ifstream::open` are all you need. When used on `ofstream` the file will be created. This is simple enough such that it could probably all live within `main` without the extra one-line functions that are only ever used once.

Answer (score 2):

> I just do not know how to take the results that are within the "void filereadernc(ifstream &file)" function and output in the text file of the "void filewriter(ofstream &file)" function

I suggest dividing the program such that you have three independent pieces:

1. Read the data.
2. Process the data.
3. Write the data.

In order to be able to do that, you have to first define what are your data. Use a `struct` to do that.

```
struct MyData
{
  // ... fill in the details.
};
```

Functions:

```
void readData(std::istream& in, MyData& data)
{
   // Read the contents of the stream and flesh out data
}

void readData(std::string const& file, MyData& data)
{
   // Read the contents of file and flesh out data
   std::ifstream in(file);
   readData(in, data);
}

void processData(MyData& data)
{
   // Do whatever you need to do to process the data.
}

void writeData(std:::ostream& out, MyData const& data)
{
   // Write the contents of the data to the stream.
}

void writeData(std:::string const& file, MyData const& data)
{
   // Write the contents of the data to the file.
   std::ofstream out(file);
   writeData(out, data);
    }
```

Now `main` can be:

```
int main()
{
   MyData data;

   // read the data.
   readData("C:/Users/Desktop/grades.txt", data);

   // Process the data.
   processData(data);

   // Write the data out to a file and std::cout
   writeData("C:/Users/Desktop/results.txt", data);
   writeData(std::cout, data);
}
```

If it makes sense, you can divide the data into input data and results data too.

```
struct InputData { ... };
struct ResultsData { ... };
```

and then update the functions appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is kinda complicated but here is the trick you can do instead of displaying the result in the terminal each time (cout) write it to the file by calling the method filewriter and passing in args what you want to write in the file.

Call the function this way:

```
filewriter(ofstream &file, sum);
```

And implement it this way:

```
void filewriter(ofstream &file, float result)
{

file << results;

}
```

Comment: What's the advantage versus the single output line?  Looks like you adding the overhead of function call and return.

Comment: Please see @R Sahu answer for an optimal solution. I just wrote a solution that goes with your implementation which is quite ugly.

Comment: I will try to use @R Sahu's answer to go forward with this, but will also try your solution and see if it works. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, please comment here if there any issues I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Still cannot figure out how to implement what your saying with my code that is posted above. I will keep giving it a go and hope for the output txt file to work and show the results i am obtaining from the filereadernc void function